# \ after the condition and the code compiles, How?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have just noticed that I have a problem in my code and it is compiled!

```
else if (xx.yy(s.t.s() - 1) < cc.vv)\
{
    s.t.b().f.e();
}
```

The problem is in the `\` at the end of the `else` if line.
How was it considered as correct?

Comment: Are you saying without the `\\` your sample from above doesn't compile?

Comment: it compiles in the both cases!